# Get value from object return character ? JS

Tags: javascript, object

I have object "game.markets":

```
{"default":"60","available":["60"]}
```

So i want get 'default's value "60" , and for that use this method:

```
console.log(Object.values(game.markets)[0]);
```

And in result get ["{"] , just first character. 
How i can get value ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `game.markets.default`?

Comment: Simply Use game.markets.default

Comment: game.markets.default  return 'undefined'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have, is a stringed object.

```js
var game = { markets: '{"default":"60","available":["60"]}' };

console.log(Object.values(game.markets)[0]);
```

What you need, is to parse the [JSON](http://json.org/) string first and then access the value.

While objects do not have ordered properties, I would not rely on the order of [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). I suggest to use the property directly with a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```js
var game = { markets: '{"default":"60","available":["60"]}' };
game.markets = JSON.parse(game.markets);

console.log(game.markets.default);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead :

```
console.log(game.markets.default);
console.log(game.markets.available);
```

Comment: Return undefined

Comment: So you need to parse it first: `JSON.parse(game.markets)`

Comment: yes ,its start work with JSON.parse(game.markets) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via object syntax:

```
game.markets.default
```

or array syntax

```
game.markets["default"]
```

but if you prefer the [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) version this works well too:

```
Object.values(game.markets)[0]
```

Probably your issue is already in the declaration/initialization of the game variable.

```
var game = {};
game.markets = {"default":"60","available":["60"]};
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is like this:

```
var game = {};
game.market = {"default":"60","available":["60"]}
```

You can just do:

`game.market.default`

and you will get: 60